# Ubuntu Phone Gstreamer

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, phone, camera, gstreamer

I want make diy "RC **FPV Camera**" using **Gstreamer**,

**Hardware** : Pi + Camera + Battery + WiFi + GSM

**Software** : v4l2 or uvc + gstreamer + mjpeg or h264 encoding

but instead buy Pi, i want to buy Ubuntu phone, because it have all hardware i want.

Can **Ubuntu Phone** Run **Gstreamer** ?

Comment: It can, but why not use the raspberry ubuntu release for the Pi ?

Comment: because smart phone is compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone images use GStreamer for media, yes. The supported API for building a phone app which uses the camera or microphone, however, is not GStreamer directly. It is the Qt multimedia APIs via the QML API.

Comment: Thank you, What about commands (ifconfig , iwconfig) ?

Comment: That is a separate question, and yes, the commands are there, but again, not really how network is meant to be managed there. NetworkManager is used, and there is GUI and APIs for controlling network. Also, asking a bunch of questions on here about how things work on an Ubuntu phone is probably not the best way to learn them. :)